# AutoHotKey not working with OBS off-focus

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to use AutoHotKey with following script:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 300000
Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {Ctrl Down}{F10}{Ctrl UP}
Return
```

So it can send Key (Control + F10) which I have choose in OBS Hotkeys to run a media.
The script is working fine while OBS is Active, but when OBS became in-active or off-focus, script won't send Ctrl+F10 to OBS.

Any solution please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For sending keys to inactive windows you should use ControlSend, [check here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) for documents, windows shouldn't be minimized.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 300000
Return

PressTheKey:
ControlFocus,, OBS 27.2.3
Sleep, 10
ControlSend,, {LCtrl Down}{F10}{LCtrl Up}, OBS 27.2.3
Return
```

This might work but ControlSend doesn't work with all applications so you will need to test and find out.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
```

2 is for finding the some parts of title of the windows you want to use but if there are more windows included OBS in it's name it might make problem so you can add some more parts of the window like OBS 27.0.0 or only mid part like, Profile: Streaming..etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help but no luck. It's not sending key, neither on Active nor inactive OBS.

Comment: Just edited the answer since difficult to give it a shape in here comments. I just installed OBS and added Mute and Unmute hotkeys, works for me like this. Could you try again? Remember to change title name if it's different than yours. Sorry for posting without testing on first reply.
And it start sending the keys after first timer ends, 5mins after launching it, not straightly after launch.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and help, but it still not working all all. I might sound silly here, is there any chance I am using 2 monitors that's why it is causing issue? I have added WindowSpy image in original post. The Title same is same.